# Functional analysis, weak* convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

in lecture notes in the Internet i found the following example for weak and weak* convergence.

The unit vectors $\{e_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ converges in $l_1$ weak* towards $0 $ but not weak to $0$.

$e_n \not\stackrel{w}{\rightarrow} 0$: For the dual of $l_1$ we know, that $l_1^* \cong l_\infty$ holds. For example the sequence $y=(1,1,1,1,1,....) $ is in $l_\infty$ and we geht $y(e_n)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty e_ny_i=y_i \stackrel{n\rightarrow \infty}{\not\rightarrow} 0$, hence not weak convergent.

I think this is correct, but I do not understand the following explanation for the weak* convergence:\ 
For a sequence $(f_j)_{j\in \mathbb{N}}\in c_0$ we get $f_j(e_n)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty f_je_n=f_n\stackrel{n\rightarrow \infty}{\rightarrow}0 $

If the sequence is really taken out of $c_0$ I understand the explanation, but for weak* convergence the sequence is normally taken out of the dual, in our case the $l_1^*$ which is not conjugated to $c_0$. In addition it holds $c_0 \subset l_\infty$ so we can´t consider $l_1^*\cong l_\infty$ as a subset of $c_0$ and use the property of $c_0$, as for example in the cases of $l_p$ for $p\in (1,\infty)$.

Now I ask myself, is this example correct? It would be great, if somebody can explain it.
Thanks in advance. 
Hias

Comment: Nomenclature is here somewhat misleading. Weak*  convergence refers to the linear functionals from the pre-dual $c{_0}$ of $l{_1}$.

Answer (score 3):

You got some things confused here:

For **weak convergence**, you can take any normed vector space $X$. Then, $x_n \to x$ weakly means $\varphi(x_n)\to \varphi(x)$ for all $\varphi \in X^\ast$.

For **weak $\ast$ convergence**, you need to know that $X = Y^\ast$ is a dual space. Then, $x_n \to x$ in weak $\ast$ means $x_n (y)\to x(y)$ for all $y \in Y$, where I interpreted elements of $X$ as functionals on $Y$. And indeed, you can check $\ell^1 = (c_0)^\ast$.